# How to create a custom dialog box to acknowledge form submission?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a form on a page, and want to acknowledge the form submission with a "Thank you.Your response was recorded" custom dialog box, or perhaps a lights off background and a light focused center where I display this message.How can I do this?Would **display** attribute help me here?Or is there some other way to do it?

Comment: `position:absolute` may help. It's up to you. You're the designer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use some kind of modal window.
For example, [Twitter bootstrap modal](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/javascript.html#modals)

Then trigger the modal when the form is submitted.

```
$('form').on('submit', function(){
    $('#myModal').modal('show');
});
```

Or you could use some kind of lightbox plugin.

Good luck!

Comment: That's a neat way.Thanks :)